# Python3 / Beautifulsoup: Process HTML, get naked text & keep HTML entities

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-entities

How can I get the naked text out of HTML files after processing them with Beautifulsoup while keeping the HTML entities?

I am putting together many HTML files to a large and simple XML file.
Only 2-3 tags as well as the naked text of the HTMLs is relevant, that's why I use Beautifulsoup's (bs4) `get_text()` at the very end.

Since `get_text()` automatically "prints" out the HTML entities (&amp, --> &) the XML becomes not well-formed.

So far, I tried to reconstruct the entities with regex, but this was far from sufficient and still needs manual corrections. 
I was wondering if there is a precise way, preferably with bs4.

I would really appreciate any hint!

PS: I am aware of bs4's "formatter" argument but this is only meant for `prettify()`, `encode()`, and `decode()`.

Comment: Try using HTML Tidy

Comment: Can I combine tidy HTML with Beautifulsoup? And if so, how? The problem is that I have to work with some of the tags first, using bs4, and only then extract the text and put it with HTML entities into the XML. I gonna add this to my question above...